# JSESSIONID added to URL when Weblogic redirects to Apache?

Tags: apache, servlets, weblogic, httpsession, jsessionid

Our application is running on WebLogic.

At some point the WebLogic is redirecting to Apache to allow the user to access PDF files.

This happens via:

```
final String encodedURL = resp.encodeRedirectURL(redirectURL);                
resp.sendRedirect(encodedURL); //ok here because redirection to other  server and not  to itself
```

The problem is that WebLogic appends a JSESSIONIDto the URL and the apache fails to serve the PDF Document.

How can I prevent WebLogic from adding the JSESSIONID to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point en `encodeRedirectURL` is to include the session ID in the URL if necessary. f you think it's not necessary to include it, don't encode the URL:

```
resp.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was, that in our weblogic.xml cookies were disabled:

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
<session-descriptor>
    <cookies-enabled>false</cookies-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
```

whe solved the issue by setting them to true. in this special application, this was not a problem:

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
<session-descriptor>
    <cookies-enabled>true</cookies-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my Facelets based application's web.xml avoids JSESSIONID:

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```